# Visual Studio designer stops recognising changes occasionally

Tags: visual-studio, designer

Using VS2008 visual designer occasionally the designer seems to stop recognising changes.  Normally you get a * next to the filename in the tabs when a change is made but sometimes this stops appearing when I am making changes.  When this happens may changes are getting "lost" so if I close/reopen the file all my changes are gone.

Has anyone else encountered this and know why it happens and if there's a fix/workaround?

Cheers.

Comment: There are lots of visual designers.  Which one are you talking about.

Comment: WinForms designer I guess.  In a C# class, r-click -> View Designer.

Answer (score 3):

We ran into a similar problem in Visual Studio 2010. When attempting to resize a user control, the designer simply refused to recognize that a change was made (no * shown), and when you rebuilt, all source file changes were lost.

I found [this link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B196367.aspx?searchtext=designer+loses+changes) from another person having the same problem.

After stepping back through source control and comparing the .designer.cs file for the user control and its child controls, it turned out to be the same problem.  At some point, the line:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
```

disappeared from the designer file of one of the child controls (not the user control that I was having problems with). Incidentally, within that designer file, all of the references to "this.components" were also removed.

After fixing the child control (restoring the creation of this.components, and fixing the original references), the top level user control then started recognizing changes again.

We're not sure what caused the corruption of the child control.  Perhaps it was a source code merge or a designer bug.

It's a very difficult problem to debug.  Even if you attach a debugger to debug the design time behavior of the user control (and its children), there are no exceptions thrown and there is no indication that anything is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check this out the next time it happens, fortunately not happened for a while now but at least I know what to check for!